# Storyboard UIView cuts off objects when scrolling

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, xcode4.5

Using Storyboards, I have a scrollview with a UIView embeded into it. On that UIView I have some text and a button. The button is down a bit, for this question.

When I scroll in the simulator and on the device, the UIView gets cut off where the button is. (button there to show the cut off)

[image]

Above pic is before scrolling.

[image]

This pic is showing the scroll UIView and the button embeded into it being cut off.

I have set the Size Inspector to 1000 height.

I have searched on stackoverflow and I have not found an answer as of yet.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: No, I am not using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the hierarchy of this particular window is not ordered properly. You need to rearrange your hierarchy. To do this, go to your storyboard, and click on the little button on the bottom left that looks like the play button with a box around it. From there, you can adjust.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in an app i was working on. For some reason, it didn't work for me either. I suggest you try creating the the scrollview and the view inside it programatically instead of storyboard for this particular view controller. It will work like a charm. You will also have to find the length of the inner view and then set the size of the scroll view to the size of the view embedded in it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Not sure if this is the preferred method or just a work around.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The main difference is I connected the last ScrollView, not the First one. Not sure why but it works.

[image]
[image]

Before, (pics above in original post with cut off button), it would cut off my UIView. I still would like to know "why" it does this. Thanks for the reply's.